# Can I automatically populate the AutomationId property of .NET MAUI controls?

Tags: c#, .net, maui, code-generation

I am looking for a way to automatically populate the `AutomationId` property of .NET MAUI controls in the pages of an app.

I have begun looking into .NET source generators with the great series "[Creating a source generator](https://andrewlock.net/series/creating-a-source-generator/)" by Andrew Lock to see if that's the way to go... but I'm not sure. I was thinking of using this approach to run through all the controls and set the property if not already set.

So my question is, can this be done with source generators? If not, maybe you can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that source generators are a pre-compilation/code analyzer feature. Your controls only get instantiated at runtime. Now, you could probably set a default `AutomationId` for a control or control template in the code-behind automatically using an analyzer. However, what's the purpose of all this? What's your goal?

Comment: Thanks @Julian. It is for testing purposes that I want all UI controls to have an AutomationId and I'm looking for a way to automatically set that property on all UI controls. Knowing myself, I'm sure that I would forget some if I need to do that manually.

Comment: Okay, but how would you generate the value for the identifier in the first place? When they're auto-generated, how would you know which is which?

Comment: Careful not to set the AutomationId of a control more than once as it will crash the app